# Create NxN Haar Matrix

Tags: math, image-processing, signal-processing, haar-wavelet

I can't find a definition for generating an un-normalized NxN Haar matrix. So what is the equation?

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet

Thx, Chris

Comment: The Wikipedia article gives the definition.  What part is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx all. Wikipedia gives the 'equation':

[image]

I've wrote a recursive solution for generating an un-normalized NxN Haar matrix in octave.

```
function [h] = haar(n)
h = [1];
if n > 2
    h = haar(n/2);
endif
% calculate upper haar part
h_n = kron(h,[1,1]); 
% calculate lower haar part 
h_i = kron(eye(length(h)),[1,-1]);
% combine parts
h = [h_n; h_i];
endfunction

disp(haar(8));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the algorithm for both the normalized and un-normalized [Haar matrix](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/Haar/index.html) based on the `recursive formula for the Haar matrix`:

[image]

from the paper "Discrete wavelets and perturbation theory" by W-H Steeb, et al. Here is the implementation in Python

```py
def haarMatrix(n, normalized=False):
    # Allow only size n of power 2
    n = 2**np.ceil(np.log2(n))
    if n > 2:
        h = haarMatrix(n / 2)
    else:
        return np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])

    # calculate upper haar part
    h_n = np.kron(h, [1, 1])
    # calculate lower haar part 
    if normalized:
        h_i = np.sqrt(n/2)*np.kron(np.eye(len(h)), [1, -1])
    else:
        h_i = np.kron(np.eye(len(h)), [1, -1])
    # combine parts
    h = np.vstack((h_n, h_i))
    return h
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you want to achieve. The Haar matrix is the 2x2 DCT matrix, so inversly, you can treat the NxN DCT(II) matrix as the Haar matrix for that block size.

Or if the N is dyadic, N=2^n, then you might be asking for the transform matrix for n stages of the Haar transform. Which might be a problem because of the sampling rate decimation in each step.

Answer (score 0):

```
def HT(N):
    if N == 1: return np.array([[1]])
    return 1/np.sqrt(2)*np.concatenate(
        (
            np.kron(HT(N//2),[1,1])
        ,
            np.kron(np.identity(N//2),[1,-1])
        ),axis = 0
        )
```

I used the equation in Wikipedia adding a normalization factor `1/sqrt(2)`. The matrix becomes orthonormal. Does it work?